# using minio for gitlab docker registry

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, docker-registry

The standard configuration for aws s3 does not work for minio local s3 storage. 
Can someone share the minio specific configuration that works for storing docker registry images.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a config that will work for minio

`version: 0.1
log:
    fields:
        service: registry
http:
    addr: :5000
storage:
    cache:
        layerinfo: inmemory
    s3:
        accesskey: minio
        secretkey: minio123
        region: us-east-1
        regionendpoint: http://172.17.0.1:9000
        bucket: docker-registry
        encrypt: false
        secure: false
        v4auth: true
        chunksize: 5242880
        rootdirectory: /`

`FROM registry:2.6
COPY config.yml /etc/docker/registry/config.yml`

Comment: hi thanks , how can this be done for omnibus gitlab.rb file format? and is there anyway to migrate existing images to new storage configured.

Comment: Hi, I am not very familiar with `omnibus gitlab.rb file format`. Can you please point me to documentation on that? You should be able to migrate existing images to new storage.

Comment: this is the rb file format: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/files/gitlab-config-template/gitlab.rb.template  , there are proper receipes for doing the same for lfs and artifacts , how to use minio and how to do the migration using gitlabctl migrate commands but i could not found the same for registry.